# Laravel 5: get custom message from Exception on view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5 my code as :

```
$data = Contents::whereSlug($content)->orWhere('id', '=', $content)->first();
```

maybe return `null`. I want to manage that with custom message and show that on view. for example:

```
Route::get('/showContent/{content}', function ($content) {
    $data = Contents::whereSlug($content)->orWhere('id', '=', $content)->first();
    if ($data == null) {
        abort(404, 'content not found');
    }
    $serverInformation = ServerInformation::find(1);
    return view('layouts.frontend.pages.showContent', compact(
        'data',
        'serverInformation'
    ));
});
```

I have `errors` folder on `resources/views/missing.blade.php` now I expect this message as `content not found` show on view by this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h2>{{ $exception->getMessage() }}</h2></body>
</html>
```

unfortunately I get this error:

```
Undefined variable: exception (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alachiqServer/resources/views/errors/missing.blade.php
```

and `render` on `Handler.php` file:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException or $e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->view('errors.missing', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

how can I solve this problem? [resource](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-laravel-404-page-using-custom-exception-handlers)

Comment: try composer dump-autoload and make view file name as 404.blade,php under view/errors

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, my update code:

```
return response()->view('errors.missing', compact('exception'), 404);
```